# Objective-C to Swift, pointer conversion

Tags: objective-c, pointers, swift

I'm trying to implement the Objective-C library, ORSSerialPort into my Swift project.

The example provided with the library provides the following setup for the ORSSerialPortManager class:

```
ORSSerialPortManager *portManager = [ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager];
```

Should something such as this not be able to take it's place in Swift?

```
ORSSerialPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
```

Perhaps with the pointer something like this?

```
ORSSerialPortManager = withUnsafePointer(&ORSSerialPortManager, ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager())
```

I get the errors: 'Cannot assign to the result of this expression', and 'Expressions are not allowed at the top level'. What has to change?

Comment: The first syntax is correct. Have you added the .h file for the Objective-C class to your bridging header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression:

```
ORSSerialPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
```

is trying to assign to a type name (`ORSSerialPortManager`). This is the reason for the "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" error; the expression `ORSSerialPortManager` is not assignable. Instead, you want to assign to a new variable name:

```
let aPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
```

Or, if you want a non-constant reference:

```
var aPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
```

You can also put the type annotation on the variable, but it's not needed here (it can be deduced from the method signature):

```
var aPortManager : ORSSerialPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
```

Notice the change in order for types on names: `name : Type` rather than `Type name`.